# Copy oldest file to another directory using Python

Tags: python

There are some problems in my python program.

I want to open a directory, choose the oldest file and then copy the file to another directory.

I read the documents where "shutil" is mentioned, but I don't know how to choose the oldest one.

Could someone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example compares modification date, but you can of course change it to get other file-related times by changing the definition of `gt` to `os.path.getctime` or `os.path.getatime`, for example.

```
import os, shutil

fromdir = '/home/mac/Desktop'
todir = '/home/mac/Desktop/tmp'
gt = os.path.getmtime  #change if you want something else
oldest = min([(f, gt(f)) for f in os.listdir(fromdir)])[0]
shutil.move(fromdir + '/' + oldest, todir)
```

Comment: On UNIX ctime is the time of the last file status change, only the creation time on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`os.path.getatime`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getatime) to get the last access time for a file (or directory), or [`ps.path.getmtime`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) to get the time of the last modification.

Comment: You mean time of modification for `getmtime`?

Comment: @Eli: Yes I do - fixed, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This didn't work for me. It seemed to return the minimum file name (i.e. alphabetically the one nearest 'a').

Reversing the file info and file name in the tuple (     gt(f),f     ) fixed it for me. I therefore had to up the index for the returned result (the [1]).

```
oldest = min([   (     gt(f),f     ) for f in os.listdir(fromdir)])[1]
```